# Using ifeq to test the variables

Tags: makefile

I tried to write this dynamic target to check the variable before running the actual target:

```
.PHONY: check-env-%
check-env-%:
ifeq ($(${*}),)
    $(error not found ${*})
endif
```

so that I can use it like:

```
build: check-env-VERSION
```

But looks like it cannot compare it and even when I supply the required variable, it errors: `Makefile:16: *** not found VERSION. Stop.`

I believe I'm using the `ifeq` correctly but not sure why it cannot compare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vroomfondel is right. What you can do instead is this:

```
check-env-%:
    test $($*) || (echo $* not found; exit 1;)
    ...
```

`test` shall stop when there is no variable defined.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals): "Conditionals control what make actually “sees” in the makefile, so they *cannot be used to control recipes* at the time of execution."  So your access to $* always yields an empty string at the time of makefile analysis, leaving your $(error) as recipe instruction.